# Video stream for ARDRONE - ROS CV Bridge

Tags: python, opencv, ros, ar.drone

This is Kathir. While using cv and ros bridge, I am not able to ardrone's camera's output in my computer. Could somebody help me to fix this ? I am not getting any error from the python code.

```
import roslib
import sys
import rospy
import cv2
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

class image_converter:

 def __init__(self):
   print('Image converter constructor ')
   self.image_pub = rospy.Publisher("image_topic_2",Image,queue_size=1)

   self.bridge = CvBridge()
   self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("image_topic",Image,self.callback)

 def callback(self,data):
   try:
     cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
   except CvBridgeError as e:
     print(e)

   (rows,cols,channels) = cv_image.shape
   if cols > 60 and rows > 60 :
     cv2.circle(cv_image, (50,50), 10, 255)
   print('Above imshow function')
   cv2.imshow("Image window", cv_image)
   cv2.waitKey(3)

   try:
     self.image_pub.publish(self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image, "bgr8"))
   except CvBridgeError as e:
     print(e)


def main(args):
 ic = image_converter()
 print('inside main ')
 rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
 try:
   rospy.spin()
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
   print("Shutting down")
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print('Function call started ')
   main(sys.argv)
```

There is no error in the code. But I am not getting the output of ARDRONE from my laptop ?

Any suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: 1) You have some prints in your code - which ones are output? 2) Can you check with `rosgraph` that your node is actually connected to a topic? 3) If you are actually connected, can you check using `rostopic hz image_topic` that there is actually data on that topic?

Comment: imshow is the output to see the video stream using cv2

Comment: Print statements are just for debugging purpose.

Comment: Obviously. But aren't you asking us to debug your code? ;-) And more importantly, did you run `rosgraph` / `rostopic hz`?

Comment: rostopic hz doesn't work. 
rosgraph - Nodes:
  /rosout :
    Inbound:
    Outbound:
Services:
  /rosout/set_logger_level
  /rosout/get_loggers

Comment: The above code is found in ROS website for video stream.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you not get any output, do you get an error message, do you get anything else? You need to provide more details if you want us to help you! Also, what is the rest of your setup - are you running the ARDRONE nodes (which would provide `image_topic`)? What does "rosnode list" say? Without more details it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I tried rostopic echo /ardrone/image_raw

[ INFO] [1485107589.786808704]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/kathirdrone/.ros/camera_info/ardrone_front.yaml [ INFO] [1485107589.787710768]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/kathirdrone/.ros/camera_info/ardrone_front.yaml] [ WARN] [1485107589.788890283]: Camera calibration file /home/kathirdrone/.ros/camera_info/ardrone_front.yaml not found.